# log verbose output from mysqldump to both to console and text file

Tags: windows, console-application, mysql, database-administration

I want to log verbose output from mysqldump to both to console and text file

The following command sends the verbose output to console

```
MySQLDump -v -h localhost -u root MyDb > MyDB.Bak
```

The following command sends the verbose output to **MyDB.txt** file

```
MySQLDump -v -h localhost -u root MyDb > MyDB.Bak 2> MyDb.txt
```

But I Want to verbose output to go to console and to txt file in the single command

Any help is appreciated

Comment: See my answer. If it resolves your problem, then please accept it

Answer (score 1):

For this, use the `tee` utility.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee